# Child div display table-cell fixed width not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to stretch a child div to the full height of parent by using `display: table-cell` on the child, but I want the child width to stay within a container and the child ignores the width property and is always 100% width.

I have tried adding `table-layout: fixed` to the parent, setting a `max-width: 100px` to the child but it does not seem to affect the child div.

I have the following layout:

```
<div class="parent">

  <div class="child">

    //Content Here

  </div>

</div>
```

And the Following CSS

```
.parent {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.child {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Example: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/enriqg9/y59tvcem/)

************** UPDATE **************

I was able to achieve the desired behavior by using display: flex and flex-direction: column on .parent and flex: 1 on .child, however i am not sure if this is the best solution because of browser compatibility.

See updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/enriqg9/y59tvcem/4/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a grand-child `div`

here is a snippet:

```css
.parent {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
    min-height: 500px;
}
.child {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 5% /* demo */
}
.grand-child {
    background: white;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <div class="grand-child">Blue Background not visible due to .child taking width 100%</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE** (*based on OP comment*)

> Thank you, but then the child/grand-child div is not full height of
>   the parent

So here is an explanation/Solution:

### Explanation:

`min-height` doesn't apply to [table elements](http://ttp://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#min-max-widths)

> In CSS 2.1, the effect of `min-width` and `max-width` on tables,
>   inline tables, table cells, table columns, and column groups is
>   undefined.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height):

> Applies to all elements but non-replaced inline elements, table
>   columns, and column groups

[image: browser compatibility]

So, you can replace `min-height` with `height`, because `table` always stretch.

### Solution:

```css
/* Both Single and Multiple Cells */

.parent {
  display: table;
  box-sizing:border-box; /*see vendor-prefixes */
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  height: 500px;
}
.child {
  display: table-cell;
}
.child .parent{
  width: 100px;
  background: white;
}


/* Multiple "Cells" extra */

  /*if you want to have more than one .child.parent display in same .row either you set them float:left or .display:inline-block (maybe with some margin-left/right) - added multiple justfor demo puposes */

.parent .multiple {
  float:left;
  margin-right:6%;
}
```

```html
<h1> single "Cell" </h1>

<hr />

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="parent">Blue Background not visible due to .child taking width 100%</div>
  </div>
</div>


<!--

HOW THIS CODE WORKS:

<table> // parent
    <tr> -- ommited in the code above --
        <td> //child
            <table> // child parent
            </table>
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>

-->

<h1> Multiple "Cells" </h1>

<hr />

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="parent multiple">Blue Background not visible due to .child taking width 100%</div>
    <div class="parent multiple">Blue Background not visible due to .child taking width 100%</div>
    <div class="parent multiple">Blue Background not visible due to .child taking width 100%</div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--

HOW THIS CODE WORKS:

<table> // parent
    <tr> -- ommited in the code above --
        <td> //child
            <table> // child parent
            </table>
            <table> // child parent
            </table>
            <table> // child parent
            </table>
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>

-->
```

Comment: Thank you, but then the child/grand-child div is not full height of the parent

Comment: I could easily set `min-height` to child, but in my actual development parent's `min-height` is variable to the height of viewport with js. I am trying to find a css only solution to stretch child to the height of parent but stay within a certain width.

Comment: its 5am right now, I'll take a look at this tomorrow, meanwhile see  [this](https://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/)

Comment: I was able to achieve the desired behavior by using `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column` on .parent and `flex: 1` on .child, however i am not sure if this is the best solution because of browser compatibility.

Comment: If you can wait a few hours.. I'll try to give you an updated answer with a more cross browser.

Comment: I just updated my answer, please take a look, and sorry for the delay.  even for not paying attention for small details in my first answer, but was at the time 4 or 5am, therefore very tired.

Comment: Thank you, but I think that this is a more complex solution than just setting both divs to `display: block` and then setting `min-height: 500px` to `.child` and the result will be the same since it really is the `min-height: 500px` that is stretching the child to the height of parent. See this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/enriqg9/y59tvcem/6/).

Comment: my solution is based on you wanting a `display:table/table-cell` - *I am trying to stretch a child div to the full height of parent by using `display: table-cell`* -  and because I understand you wanted a "dynamic" height as well - *I could easily set `min-height` to child, but in my actual development parent's min-height is variable to the `height` of viewport with js*, - So to have **both** I came up this solution which is **cross-browser**,, but if you don't want to use :`display:table/table-cell` then of course your last fiddle is easier and I already had that kind of solution in my mind.

Comment: btw, this is one of my best answers so far, very well explained, took me a while :)

Comment: Thank you it was very well explained indeed, but on your solution you set a fixed height to the inner `.parent` as well compared to using `display: flex` which makes the div stretch to the height of parent without using `min-height` or `height`. I will mark your answer as accepted for explaining why `width` or `min-width` does not affect `display: table-cell`.

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
.parent {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 background: blue;
 min-height: 500px;
}

.child {
 display: table-cell;
 width: 100px;
 background: white;
}
```

parent Div shall be diven as `display:block`

Working Fiddle [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/y59tvcem/1/)

Comment: if you set parent to `display:block` then `display:table-cell` in child will lose its effect, meaning having it set or not the outcome is the same.

Comment: I understand that but as per OP's concern.. it was just that child div taking 100%

Comment: @Gags by setting `display: block` to the parent div the child div is no longer the height of the parent.

Comment: @enriqg9 ... but where he asked about height... let OP accept the answer whichever suits best to him ... i answered as he asked only for child div taking 100%